# How many Possible ways to call controller's method to visual force page

Tags: visualforce, controller

How many Possible ways to call controller's method to visual force page 
except button action attribute

Comment: This is literally first click on google search. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_methods.htm

Answer (score 5):

These are the following ways I can thought about.

- [apex:page action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)
- [apex:commandLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm)
- [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)
- [apex:actionSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm)
- [apex:actionPoller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm)
- [Javascript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm)
- rendering pageblocktable, datatable, apex:repeat which are populating data calling controller methods.
- [Visualforce Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects.htm)

Comment: Would like to add few.

apex:CommandLink ,
JS remote Objects ,
Rest API CALL ,
SOAP API CALL ,

Comment: I didn't search those, whatever coming to my mind just writing, thanks for your input